# How to get all error with forEach function in the object directly?

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to get an array value from function if I put the forEach in the array?

Here is my code

```
res.status(400).send({
    reason: err._message,
    messages: Object.keys(err.errors).forEach((message) => {
        return message; // I want messages will be arrays from err.errors
    })
});
```

it doesn't return any error, and what I tried to achieve is the output like this

```
{
    "reason": "some message from err._message",
    "errors": {
        "name": "Name field is required",
        "etc": "etc field is required",

        ...
    }
}
```

`err.errors` output (I don't want to show all the errors)

```
"errors": {
    "name": {
        "message": "Name field is required",
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Name field is required",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "name",
            "value": ""
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "name",
        "value": ""
    }
},
```

**EDIT**

as `@jonrsharpe` comment I tried using `map`

```
res.status(400).send({
    reason: err._message,
    errors: Object.values(err.errors).map((data) => {
        return data.message;
    })
});
```

it's already give me a correct value, but I don't know how to get the key

this code returns

```
{
    "reason": "User validation failed",
    "errors": [
        "Name field is required",
        "Email field is required"
    ]
}
```

But if possible I want the errors returns as `Object`

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything, it's for side effects only; you want either map (to get an array) or reduce (which you can use to get an object)

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe, thanks for the edit! but for my question did I need to create an extra `let` or I can return it directly to the `.send({ ... })`?

Comment: You can let an object then fill it using the forEach, or use map or reduce to do it inline, you just can't do it inline with forEach.

Comment: Hi I just updated my question, can you please check? @jonrsharpe. or I can't do inline object.map?

Comment: You need to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`.

Comment: hi @NicolaeMaties, I already use the `.map()` but how to return it as object? and show the `key` as well, thanks !

Comment: You *can* inline map, but *as I already told you* (and per its docs) that gives you an array. I also mentioned what you can use to get an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please `.reduce` function from javascript.

```
Object.keys(err.errors).reduce((a,b)=>{ 
    a[b]=x.errors[b]['message']; 
    return a
}, {})
```